# How to use Jquery UI tabs and bootstrap nav bar

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling with how to use jquery-ui tabs in connection with bootstrap nav bar. I would like it so each nav button fires off an ajax call to load its content. If the content has been previously loaded, then it should re-use that content rather than making a new request.

jquery UI tabs does everything I want except that it places the content of the tab inside the nav bar. I looked at the jquery-ui tabs javascript code and it appends a div to the end of the ul list for the ajax loaded page.

**Important** asp-controller and asp-action are a new feature of ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 where it gets translated to an href link

I am striving for code-reuse rather than re-inventing the wheel and would assume this would be highly desirable in medium to large size websites.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">WebSiteTemplate</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

....

<script>
    $("#tabs").tabs();
</script>
```

Comment: try adding a fiddle to demonstrate the problem

Comment: I tried adding a fiddler here http://jsfiddle.net/kneuse/4Lh1u11x/. I am having issues getting the tabs call to work there and the external pages won't load.

Comment: jsFiddler.net does not seem to play nice with multiple pages and my example requires multiple pages since the tabs are ajax loading each page on demand. I did get the jqueryUI tabs call to work, but it does not show my bug due to the single page limitation.